# « Au mi-projet » ou « à la mi-projet » (et pourquoi) ?

Tags: genre, noms, indications-de-temps, préfixes

Est-ce que c'est « au mi-projet » ou « à la mi-projet » (et pourquoi) ? Une recherche avec Google trouve plus d'occurrences de la forme féminine.

Comment: J'ai retiré l'étiquette [tag:quebec] parce que je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il y ait une particularité québecoise ici.

Answer (score 8):

Toutes les expressions de la forme *mi-durée* qui désignent la date au milieu de l'intervalle de temps concerné sont féminines. C'est mon impression, et elle est [confirmée par le *Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mi-) (I.A.1). On dit ainsi *la mi-journée*, *la mi-janvier*, *la mi-automne*, et ainsi de suite, indépendamment du genre du mot exprimant la durée.

L'usage (une recherche Google) confirme une forte prépondérance de « à la mi-projet », « à la mi-mandat », etc. sur leurs équivalents masculins.

Je ne sais pas ce qui a imposé le féminin. On peut expliquer *à la mi-projet* comme une contraction de *à la moitié du projet*, mais aussi de *au milieu du projet*, ce qui n'aide pas.

Il y a un cas particulier : *[mi-temps](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mi-temps)*. Il ne s'agit pas là d'une durée précise. Toutefois, lorsqu'il s'agit d'une période de temps continue, le mot est bien féminin : *la mi-temps* d'un match de football. Le mot est en revanche masculin lorsqu'il désigne un travail à temps partiel ; *la mi-temps* est un instant, alors que *un mi-temps* est (avant passage à la métonymie) une durée.

Answer (score 5):

S'il faut en croire Grevisse (§476 a) 1°), le féminin se serait généralisé sous l'influence de *mi-août* désignant l'Assomption, où le « fête » sous-entendu est à l'origine du changement (les noms en « mi+mois » étant traités comme masculins en ancien français). *Mi*, qui jusque là avait été un adjectif (c'est l'évolution du latin *media*; cf. aussi l'usage archaïsant « la mi-nuit »), a alors été pris comme nom féminin.