# Pourquoi est-ce que le mot "mi-carême" feminin alors que "Carême" est masculin?

Tags: étymologie, genre, mots-composés, trait-d-union

Et est-ce qu'il y a d'autres exemples pour ce phénomène de **mi-carême** (dont j'ignore le nom) ?

Comment: Voir aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2473/au-mi-projet-ou-%c3%a0-la-mi-projet-et-pourquoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cela signifie *à la moitié du Carême*, on trouve aussi, par exemple :

> à la mi-février.

> à la mi-parcours.

Comment: @jlliagre: Effectivement...